# Disable minimize or maximize when double clicked on ribbon

Tags: wpf, ribbon, double-click, minimize, maximize

I use the Ribbon for WPF (2010 - Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon).

How can I disable the minimize or maximize effect from the red range, when I do a double click on the tab (header)

[image]

Comment: Here is your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7412853/ribboncontrolslibrary-how-to-disable-minimizing

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this event on the **SizeChanged** property of the ribbon to suppress minimizing.

```
/// <summary>
/// Disable the minimize functionality of the ribbon.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
private void RibbonSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var ribbon = sender as Ribbon;
    if (ribbon != null)
    {
        ribbon.IsMinimized = false;
    }

    // Handled
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: At the time of this post it did. The release was from 2010. If they have updated it since then it is possible this changed.